# How do bottom up parser evaluate things that need an inherited attribute?

Tags: formal-grammars, programming-languages, compilers, parsers, attribute-grammars

I learned that Bottom up parsers use only synthesized attributes to evaluate semantics.  Which makes sense considering that it would be very hard to evaluate an inherited attribute in bottom up parsing.

So, can bottom up parser evaluate pretty much anything top down parsers do without using inherited attributes? Is that possible?